# How to query relation not set

Tags: google-app-maker

I can successfully query relations that have been set:

```
var datasource = app.datasources.MyModel;
datasource.query.filters.Stage.Name._contains = 'This'; //works
datasource.query.filters.Stage.Name._contains = 'That'; //works
datasource.load();
```

I'm struggling with **how can I query relations that have NOT been set?**

I tried, to no avail:

```
datasource.query.filters.Stage.Id._equals = null; //doesnt work
datasource.query.filters.Stage._equals = null; //doesnt work
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem some time ago and it was a tricky one for me too. The solution is very simple actually. So what you are required to do is NOT use:

`datasource.query.filters.Stage.Id._equals = null;`

Instead use:

`datasource.query.filters.Stage.Id._in = [null];`

I remember I came up with this solution by reading the **[official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Query)**. Right at the part that says:

> Filters **in** and **notIn** check that the field equals (not equals) any value in a given array.

So I figured out that if I placed **null** inside an array and used the `_in` comparison it would compare against the **null** value and surprisingly, it worked! I hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfectly! thanks very much for the documentation pointer too.